# How to add values in sql? - postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, sum

I want to add the val_col based header_id and bill_name

```
Input:
bill_name header_id  va_col  id
23823     62259      40      7
23823     62259      7       8
23824     62254      20      7
23824     62254      40      9
23825     62257      10      7

Output:
bill_name header_id  total  
23823     62259      47
23824     62254      60           
23825     62257      10
```

Comment: Consider doing some research on your own. Start reading on writing SQL to fetch the whole data, then only certain coumns, then try reading on [aggregate function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/functions-aggregate.html)

Comment: If you don't know what `GROUP BY` and `SUM()` are then you should study more SQL so you can use it at least basically, if not effectively.  This is very basic syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a very basic aggregation query:

```
select bill_name, 
       header_id, 
       sum(va_col) as total
from the_table
group by bill_name, header_id;
```